How exactly does one actively network when looking for a new job?
I often hear that getting a job has more to do with networking than it does with sending in a resume to a job opening, especially these days.
What exactly does "networking" mean in this context?
For example, I found a job opening that I found intriguing. I can use LinkedIn to find the profile of current employees with similar job titles.
Now what? Should I shoot them a message to see if they can some how increase my chances of getting an interview?
I don't see this working but I'm curious how people actively peruse professional networking when they don't have a job and are looking for one?

I am verging on VTC for this as the responses are likely going to be opinion based - but I will see what other people think before voting.

Attending professional development courses or conferences (such as hosted by a software vendor) may help.  In tough times, it's hard for people to hold their own jobs, let alone hire others.

Quietly. Your employed may not like it if they hear that you're looking at other jobs (I attended an interview without realising the company was a client of my employer - didn't get the job, and they told my employer who threatened to fire me if I didn't stop interviewing).

@JosephDoggie that's actually where I got the idea from. The instructor said in this day and age almost no one hires a stranger who applied from a job posting. But she didn't really explain the steps to overcome this.

@clanlatin: The instructor is an idiot. Or is trying to market services you don't need. Or both

I’m voting to close this question because it's already addressed by the many past questions tagged "networking", and because it is based on fundamental (and marketing -based) misunderstandings of what networking means and what role it plays in the job search context.

"Hey, Fred, if you hear about a job in your company that I might be a good fit for, please call my attention to it or pass them my name or both. I'm particularly interested in X, Y, and Z, but I also have intensive experience with A, B, and C."
There's no magic here. Networking really is just asking your friends to keep an eye out for opportunities for you.
Please review past questions with the "networking" tag for more detailed description of what genuine networking is and why it is being mis-described and massively oversold.

Important point - you build your network before you need a new job, you exercise your network when you do.


How exactly does one actively network when looking for a new job?

Phone calls, emails, lunches, dinners, conferences, etc.
Presumably, you have friends within your profession. Some of those friends work at companies that have jobs to be filled. Some of those friends have friends who know of open positions.
Keep in touch. Make it know that you are looking for a job (if you are).

I'm curious how people actively peruse professional networking when
they don't have a job and are looking for one?

If you don't currently have a job, then it's even easier. You can network virtually all day, and all your lunchtimes are free.

I more meant what type of topics should I bring up and what requests should I make? For example, would I find someone with a job that seems appealing to me on LinkedIn, then message him asking if he has any ideas on how I could get a job like his?

Second @JoeStrazzere's comment. Blindly contacting random strangers about jobs that may not exist isn't networking. It's wasting effort better invested in responding to actual job listings. Unless, perhaps, you are looking for a minimum-wage position like supermarket stock clerk, where they don't bother listing the jobs because they already get more applicants than they can use.

The way you get a job like Fred's is to understand the requirements for that job, develop the skills for it, and apply for it.

Many of the jobs I've had were from recruiters.  Also, I got one from a co-worker who was related to a company owner and one from someone who sold a certain product.  However, "open" ads and recruiting firms are also an excellent way to get jobs!

"Presumably, you have friends within your profession." This is logical but I think I'm encountering a few barriers. 1) My last job was fully remote and for a small company. They were all friendly and professional but I wouldn't say I was close with anyone. 2) Most people I went to school with are also in more entry level jobs and don't hold sway over hiring decisions, or their company has strict rules to avoid nepotism in the hiring process. 3) I completed the co-op program, however some companies tanked, and some of my former managers are looking for new work too.

I guess it would be more beneficial to network with more senior employees than junior ones.

See past answers. Unless you are already friends with senior managers, they aren't in your network, and there is nothing you can do about that in time to help your current job search. Drop that idea.
